# Run code when a program is stopped via Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Our company develops some .NET applications which log on to one of our servers when starting and log off again when quitting the program. This works for our customers without any problems. However, we developers often do not terminate the programs in the regular way, but via the stop function of the Visual Studio development environment.

In this case the logout is not executed.

Is there a possibility to execute code anyway if the applications are terminated in this way?

UPDATE

I am very sure this can not be done from the application itself since it is terminated. I thinking about running some kind of script inside Visual Studio.

Comment: No.  If this is a problem for you then it is also a problem for your user.  Indistinguishable from their machine unexpectedly losing power.  You'll need to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on "Stop debugging" button, no additional code will be executed.

There is no event to catch a execute some code.

Your only way to do this, could be monitoring process externally, and call some code after application will exit.

MSDN:

Click Stop Debugging on the Debug menu to stop the target's execution and end the target process and all its threads.